# why performance of cython loop has diminished in comparison with python one in terms of speed?

Tags: python, performance, loops, cython, typed-memory-views

I am trying to improve my python code in terms of speed by using cython features.
My python code consists of `py_child` and `py_parent` classes and `py_backup` function which is like this:

```
import random
from time import clock
import numpy as np
from libc.string cimport memcmp
## python code #################################################
class py_child:
    def __init__(self, move):
        self.move = move
        self.Q = 0
        self.N = 0

class py_parent:
    def __init__(self):
        self.children = []
    def add_children(self, moves):
        for move in moves:
            self.children.append(py_child(move))

def py_backup(parent, white_rave, black_rave):
    for point in white_rave:
        for ch in parent.children:
            if ch.move == point:
                ch.Q += 1
                ch.N += 1

    for point in black_rave:
        for ch in parent.children:
            if ch.move == point:
                ch.Q += 1
                ch.N += 1
```

and this is the same implementation in `cython` by using memoryviews as some variables:

```
## cython ######################################################

cdef class cy_child:
    cdef public:
        int[:] move
        int Q
        int N
    def __init__(self, move):
        self.move = move
        self.Q = 0
        self.N = 0

cdef class cy_parent:
    cdef public:
        list children
        int[:, :] moves
    def __init__(self):
        self.children = []
    def add_children(self, moves):
        cdef int i = 0
        cdef int N = len(moves)
        for i in range(N):
            self.children.append(cy_child(moves[i]))

cpdef cy_backup(cy_parent parent_node, int[:, :] white_rave,int[:, :] black_rave):
    cdef int[:] move
    cdef cy_child ch
    for move in white_rave:
        for ch in parent_node.children:
            if memcmp(&move[0], &ch.move[0], move.nbytes) == 0:
                ch.Q += 1
                ch.N += 1

    for move in black_rave:
        for ch in parent_node.children:
            if memcmp(&move[0], &ch.move[0], move.nbytes) == 0:
                ch.Q += 1
                ch.N += 1
```

Now I want to evaluate the speed of code for functions cy_backup, py_backup.So I use this code:

```
### Setup variables #########################################
size = 11
board = np.random.randint(2, size=(size, size), dtype=np.int32)

for x in range(board.shape[0]):
    for y in range(board.shape[1]):
        if board[x,y] == 0:
            black_rave.append((x,y))
        else:
            white_rave.append((x,y))

py_temp = []
for i in range(size):
    for j in range(size):
        py_temp.append((i,j))

#### python arguments #######################################

py = py_parent()
py.add_children(py_temp)
# also py_temp, black_rave, white_rave

#### cython arguments #######################################
cy_temp = np.assarray(py_temp, , dtype= np.int32)
cy_black_rave = np.asarray(black_rave, dtype= np.int32)
cy_white_rave = np.asarray(white_rave, dtype= np.int32)
cy = cy_parent()
cy.add_children(cy_temp)

#### Speed test #################################################
%timeit py_backup(py_parent, black_rave, white_rave)
%timeit cy_backup(cy_parent, cy_black_rave, cy_white_rave)
```

when I ran the program, I was surprised by the results:

```
1000 loops, best of 3: 759 µs per loop
100 loops, best of 3: 6.38 ms per loop
```

I was expecting cython to be much more faster than python specially when memoryviews are used. 
 Why the loop in cython runs slower than loop in python? 
It would be highly appreciated if anyone has any suggestion to speed up the code in cython. 
In advance I apologize for my question including too much code.

Comment: Can you show the complete Cython source code, including imports and cimports? Meaning a file that can be run in cython to produce the C source code file.

Comment: Oh, now I understand the question. Both code examples are run in Cython, one using Python types, the other Cython types. Ok, firstly have a read of [Cython's working numpy instructions](http://cython.readthedocs.io/en/latest/src/tutorial/numpy.html). You are missing the numpy cimports, which means the generated C code needs to interface via Python and convert the typed memory views to Python objects to pass them to numpy. This is not needed and adds overhead, but Cython needs to have the numpy C definitions available to avoid it (cimport ..).

Comment: He's using memoryviews which provide an alternate way of accessing array-like objects, so the numpy cimports will provide no benefit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Cython memoryviews are really only optimised for one thing which is accessing single elements or slices (usually in a loop)

```
# e.g.
cdef int i
cdef int[:] mview = # something
for i in range(mview.shape[0]):
   mview[i] # do some work with this....
```

This type of code can be converted directly into efficient C code. For pretty much any other operation the memoryview is treated as a Python object.

Unfortunately almost none of your code takes advantage of the one thing memoryviews are good at, so you get no real speed up. Instead it's actually worse because you've added an extra layer, and a whole load of small length 2 memoryviews is going to be very bad.

My advice is really just to use lists - they're actually pretty good for this kind of thing and it isn't at all clear to me how to rewrite your code to really speed it up with Cython.

---

*Some small optimizations I've spotted:* You can get a pretty good idea of how optimised Cython is by looking at the highlighted html file generated by `cython -a`. You'll see that general iteration of a memoryview is slow (i.e. pure Python). You get an improvement by changing

```
# instead of:
# for move in white_rave:
for i in range(white_rave.shape[0]):
    move = white_rave[i,:]
```

This lets Cython iterate the memoryview in an efficient way.

You can get a bit more speed by turning off some of the safety checks for the `memcmp` line:

```
with cython.boundscheck(False), cython.initializedcheck(False):
   if memcmp(&move[0], &ch.move[0], move.nbytes) == 0:
```

(you need to `cimport cython`). If you do this and you haven't initialized `ch.move` or both memoryviews doesn't have at least one element then your program may crash.

---

I realise this isn't a helpful answer, but so long as you want to keep `child` as a Python class (event a `cdef` one) there really isn't much you can do to speed it up. You might consider changing it to a C struct (which you could have a C array of) but then you lose *all* the benefits of working with Python (i.e. you have to manage your own memory and you can't access it easily from Python code).

Comment: In your opinion, What would be the best substitute for memoryviews in this code : {python lists, numpy lists} If I want to get better performance.

Comment: This is only one function in my whole code which I modified to fit in a question. I have rewritten 3 other functions in cython which successfully had better performance than the python functions.

Comment: Are they always going to be of length 2? Because if that's true I'd probably just used a fixed size C array: `cdef class cy_child: cdef int move[2]`. Otherwise probably python lists.

Comment: In the python code I used tuple and the `move` actually implies a place in a game board. for example (0,0) implies A1 in chess board.

Comment: So I take that as a helpful answer. thanks bro, you're pro. ;-)